# How to add serial port api as a library and use it in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-ndk, serial-port

I am working on developing monitoring android app, using android studio. I would like to add android-serialport-api (https://code.google.com/p/android-serialport-api/) as a library in my app and make serial communication possible in the project. I downlaod sources using SVN check out and using Cygwin. I was compiling NDK file and JNI File in serial port api then I copied all files and attached in the libraries file in my project. The project structure as below.

[image: Project structure]

and then I included the build.gradle file in android-serial-api like this.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
  }
 }
apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 23
  buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {

    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']

        manifest.srcFile 'project/res/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
}
```

}

I included this in app/build.gradle

```
compile project(':libraries:android-serialport-api')
```

In settings.gradle I also included this.

```
  include ':libraries:android-serialport-api'
```

androidmanifest.xml file is originally like this.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="android_serialport_api.sample"
android:versionCode="3"
android:versionName="1.2" >

 <application
android:icon="@drawable/icon"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:name="Application" >
<activity
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name="MainMenu" >
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name="SerialPortPreferences" >
</activity>
<activity android:name="ConsoleActivity" >
</activity>
<activity android:name="LoopbackActivity" >
</activity>
<activity android:name="Sending01010101Activity"></activity>
</application>



<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />

</manifest>
```

However, when I make the project. there are lots of error. So erased most of the codes. so now androidmanifest.xml in library is like this.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="android_serialport_api.sample"
   android:versionCode="3"
   android:versionName="1.2" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />

</manifest>
```

After erasing them, I can make the project and gradle sycronized. But I don't know how to use serial.c sources from library I imported. How can I fix the program? There are some messages in the todo list.

Please help me!!

Answer (score 1):

## is simple!

- use this : [Hello Jni](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-studio-jni/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0)
- install ndk from android sdk

### for use ".so" file in other projects :

- android studio create ".so" file in this address : "app\build\intermediates\binaries\debug\lib"
- create "jniLibs" folder in "app\src\main"
- copy abi folders contain .so file in jnilibs folder
- read this : [about .so file](http://ph0b.com/android-abis-and-so-files/)

but when in loop send data, file close!!